# MongoKit's callable object has no attribute 'find_and_modify'

Tags: python, pymongo, mongokit

I'm using MongoKit as ODM framework. I have object User:

```
class User(Document):
    __collection__ = 'users'
    ...
```

There is no `__database__` here - I'm using different ones depend on current profile (development, testing etc.) I use queries like this to access data:

```
app.db.User.one({'email_confirmation_token.hex': token_hex})
```

It works fine. Now I need to use find_and_modify command. According to [documentation](http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/update.html#find-and-modify), I should call this method from collection to get dict or from object to get object.

This call works:

```
app.db.users.find_and_modify({'email_confirmation_token.hex': token_hex}, {'$set': {'active': True}})
```

but this - doesn't:

```
app.db.User.find_and_modify({'email_confirmation_token.hex': token_hex}, {'$set': {'active': True}})
```

Error message is: **AttributeError: 'CallableUser' object has no attribute 'find_and_modify'**.

Why it doesn't contain this attribute?

Answer (score 1):

find_and_modify() is missing in the source code, despite being documented. Try this:

```
app.db.User.collection.find_and_modify({'email_confirmation_token.hex': token_hex}, {'$set': {'active': True}})
```